# Output resistance of common-emitter amplifier

Tags: transistors

[image]

Assuming the circuit here is correct, would the output resistance be Vout/Iout where Iout is Vout*g0+Vout*Gc?

Answer (score 1):

> *Assuming the circuit here is correct, would the output resistance be
> Vout/Iout where Iout is Voutg0+VoutGc?*

The output resistance is \$R_B||r_0||R_C\$.

No need to make things complicated: -

[image]

Comment: Andy aka, may I ask you WHY you have shorted Vin? I think, the ouput resistance is an interesting parameter especially under operational conditions. In this case, we have to consider the "inverse" MILLER effect.

Comment: It’s a voltage source and so feedback is of no concern for this actual model. A bit like why Miller capacitance is not a big concern in common base circuits or transistor models with a hard base voltage such as common emitter.

Comment: Of course, you are right. I am very sorry - there was something like a short circuit in my brain...such things happen from time to time....